# How to list several rasters in a loop?

Tags: r, loops

I am here to ask you one question and lets see if some of you could answer me... I am trying to create a loop to extract several layers, where each layer corresponds to one variable. After this, the loop tries to group some of these layers in a more general category.

The script works but, when he starts to create the list of layers that i would like to group, R makes me an error.

```
     ========> PERIOD  2015 <======== 
    Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

    Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
      Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

I think that the main problem is in the paste0 that you will find in the #import files by category# step.

```
setwd(path_LU_fut)

for(period in periods) {
  cat("\n ========> PERIOD ",period, "<======== \n")
  
  #read netcdf file#
  eval(parse(text = paste0("ras_",period," = brick()")))
  ncpath = "/home/joanpere/Modelling_data/path_LU_fut/"
  ncname = paste0("GCAM_Demeter_LU_O_ssp5_rcp85_miroc_", period)
  ncfname = paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc", sep = "")
  
  #separate for variables, crop and scale#
  for(varis in vari) {
    eval(parse(text = paste0("ras_",period,"_",varis," = brick()")))
    ras = brick(ncfname, varname = varis)

   #import files by category#
    
   if(period == 2015) { 
     ras_2015_forest = stack(paste0("ras_",period,"_PFT",1:8))
     ras_2015_RID = stack(paste0("ras_",period,"_PFT12"), paste0("ras_",period,"_PFT31"))
     ras_2015_crop = stack(paste0("ras_",period,"_PFT",15:30))
     ras_2015_no_forest = stack(paste0("ras_",period,"_PFT",9:14))
   }

  }
}
```

Could someone help me, please?

Thanks,

Joan Pere.

Comment: I think `stack` needs the full names of the files, including the path and the extension. You could manually write the full names or retrieve them with `list.file("direcotry/where/you/have/file",full.names=TRUE)